# I need to transfer Windows XP to a new computer

Tags: windows-7

I bought a used computer from my office.  Windows XP, Pro had been removed.   They gave me a CD to reinstall.  Everything works now except the Office Suite.  How do I get Office Suite activated?

Comment: To activate Windows software, you have to have a product key. If you weren't provided with one when you purchased the used computer, then you would need to purchase one.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Windows XP does not come including Microsoft Office, as these are different software products.
This means you need two licence keys, one for Windows XP and another one for Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 0):

Office is NOT part of XP.
It is a separate product and needs it's own license key.
You will have to buy one if it wasn't included with the used computer.
(I would be every surprised if you did get a valid MS-Office key from your employer. 
In most cases a business-license for MS-Office can not legally be re-sold to a 3rd party.)